# Laravel 7 - How can I change database at login?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-7

I have several databases in my laravel 7 project.
I have a 'master' database, where I associate a user with another secondary database.
So, the master database is always the same, but the secondary database is different, depending on the users. How can I select the database when the user logs in?

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple db connections on `config/database.php`

And when user logs in, change the config value of this variable according to the user info.

Let's say you have added a new db connection called `tenant_db` and user's target dbname is "tenant_user_db_1", username is "tenant_user_1", password is "tenant_user_1_password"

Then you can change the db connection using this

```
$connection = "tenant_db";
$dbname = "tenant_user_db_1";
$username = "tenant_user_1";
$password = "tenant_user_1_password";

config(['database.connections.'.$connection.'.database' => $database]);

config(['database.connections.'.$connection.'.username' => $username]);

config(['database.connections.'.$connection.'.password' => $password]);

DB::reconnect($connection);
```

Comment: I did it in the LoginController, but then I get an SQLSTATE [3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following way to change the database.

```
config()->set('database.default', 'user-1-db');
```

PS: The above would change the database connection for a single request only. So to achieve it as per the user, you can do so by creating a middleware. Learn about middleware [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware).